# Vagrant / VirtualBox (Mac OS): The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status error

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox, vvv-wordpress

I'm running `Vagrant` version `2.2.19` with `VirtualBox` version `6.1` on `Mac OS Monterey` version `12.3.1`.

When running `vagrant up` or `vagrant up --provision`, I'm receiving the following error:

```
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Upon checking the logs, in `provisioner-utility-source-core.log` I can see the following log:

```
[0;38;5;2m ▷ Running the [0m[1m[0;38;5;5m'utility-source-core'[21m[0;38;5;2m provisioner...[0m[0m[0m
[0m[39m[2m* Updating the "core" utility on the "master" branch...[21m[0m
fatal: unsafe repository ('/srv/provision/utilities/core' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /srv/provision/utilities/core
[0;38;5;9m ! The [0m[1m[0;38;5;5m'utility-source-core'[21m[0;38;5;9m provisioner ran into problems, the full log is available at [0m[1m[0;38;5;5m'/var/log/provisioners/2022.04.18_18-32-31/provisioner-utility-source-core.log'[21m[0;38;5;9m. It completed in [0m[1m[0;38;5;5m0[21m[0;38;5;9m seconds.[0m[0m
```

In the above, can see a fatal error:

```
unsafe repository ('/srv/provision/utilities/core' is owned by someone else)
```

However, I cannot see any resources online to solve the above fatal error.

What I've tried:

1. Running `vagrant halt` then `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up` to create the box again, and then running `vagrant up` to see if it solves things (get the same error)
2. Added `Git SSH` ([using this guide](https://jhooq.com/github-permission-denied-publickey/)) in case it was a `Git` error
3. Uninstalled and then reinstalled `VirtualBox`
4. Cleared out `IPs` from `/etc/hosts/hosts`, and then ran `vagrant up` again, to see if there were any conflicts.
5. Have tried running `git config --global --add safe.directory /srv/provision/utilities/core`, then re-ran `vagrant up --provision` - but it does nothing.

**Note**: I have allowed `oracle` permissions via `security and privacy` and have rebooted my machine so it's in effect.

Is there any way to get VVV running again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that was fixed in newer versions of VVV. Update to at least VVV 3.10.1 and re-provision.

If it is still happening despite updating to newer VVV, raise a GitHub issue.

---

I'm the VVV project lead, usually when we see these issues we fix them, this isn't something you should need to fix yourself. But if you use stackoverflow to report bugs we don't see it. **Either raise a GitHub issue or ask in the VVV slack.**

https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/new/choose